# Why does retrieving html from inside a NOSCRIPT return htmlentities?

Tags: jquery

Considering the code:

```
<noscript><div>FOO</div></noscript>
```

Running

```
$('noscript').html();
```

returns `&lt;div&gt;FOO&lt;/div&gt;`

but running

```
$('noscript').text();
```

returns the raw html.

This is the opposite of what I was expecting. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: As far as I can remember, using text() won't ever return HTML tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This more of a DOM quirk than a jQuery quirk:

```
$("<noscript><div>FOO</div></noscript>")[0].innerHTML == "&lt;div&gt;FOO&lt;/div&gt;"

$("<noscript><div>FOO</div></noscript>")[0].textContent == "<div>FOO</div>"
```

Basically, behavior for this action isn't consistent, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620896/access-contents-of-noscript-with-javascript/620955#620955) explains.

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a PhantomJS bug that seems to escape the entities in the noscript tags in page.content. This function will return them to their rightful form.  The [S object](https://npmjs.org/package/string) is from the string package available on npmjs.org.

```
function fixNoScript(content) {
  var noscript = /<\s*noscript\s*>([^<]+)<\s*\/\s*noscript\s*>/ig;
  var matches = content.match(noscript);
  for ( var i = 0; match && i < matches.length; i++ ) {
    var decoded = S(matches[i]).decodeHTMLEntities().s;
    var index = content.indexOf(matches[i]);
    content = content.substring(0, index) + 
              decoded +
              content.substring(index + matches[i].length);

  }
  return content;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I advocate using regex to solve this problem.  Seems to me a good HTML Parser like Cheerio might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

yep, this is totally inconsistent since htmlentities are destroyed. &copy is always converted to the copyright character in BOTH functions. Basically there should be a function that just extracts the html as it is , whithout doing ANY conversions.