# jQuery: How can I get the HTML from inside NoScript to display in a differend div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a small script that detects if the user is using a certain browser

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if(is_chrome){
    $('.ifChrome').attr('style', 'display:block;');
    $('.ifChrome').html($('noscript > div').html());
};
```

If they are using this browser, we want to display a div tag and show the HTML from a different div tag inside.

```
<noscript>
    <div class="note">
        Your browser does not properly support the WMD Markdown Editor.<br />
        Please use <a href="/about/markdown" target="_blank">Markdown<.a> to style your input.
    </div>
</noscript>
<div class="hidden ifChrome note"></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is show the "not supported" text from inside my `<noscript>` tag to users who are using this browser (because WMD Markdown doesn't work properly with it).

My existing Javascript is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work in Chrome? It seems to work for me...

Comment: The div shows, but the content of the `noscript > div` does not get displayed in the `<div class="ifChrome">`... Instead it's just blank.

Comment: I meant that WMD Markdown seems to work.

Comment: Parts of it work, parts don't. I can't get the blockquote or the lists working proper. This is a known issue because of the way the Chrome regex works.

Comment: Can't you just put the same text inside the Chrome note? :))

Comment: Yes, that's how I have it currently. I'm just slightly concerned about a search bot seeing the content twice since they don't use Javascript.

Comment: I did however find the `class="robots-nocontent"` attribute that can help me tell robots not to index the content of the div. Maybe I'll just do that.

Comment: I still can't work out what doesn't work, but I believe you. My solution would be to put the text string into the Javascript. Hacky, but this isn't exactly a clean solution.

Comment: I've just put the input into the page twice and add the `robots-nocontent` attribute to the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access the content of a noscript-element using javascript in chrome. So you'll have to find a different approach that doesn't use a noscript-element. Read more about that problem 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620896/access-contents-of-noscript-with-javascript)

Comment: Maybe you couldn't in 2011 but you can now.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit late but you can do:

```
var noscriptContents = $($('noscript').html());
$('.ifChrome').append(noscriptContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<noscript id="noscript-main">
      <div id="div-inside-noscript">
        <span>Your content here</span>
      </div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div class="no-action">2</div>
 </noscript>
 <div id="show"></div>
<script>
      var noscript_main  = $(`#noscript-main`);
      var noscript_main_text = noscript_main.text();
      $.each($(noscript_main_text),function(k,v){
        var obj = $(v);    
        // if you want get the id of element:    
        if( obj.get(0).tagName == `DIV` ) {
          console.log( obj.prop(`id`));
        }
        //if you want display div-inside-noscript inside div#show
        if(obj.prop(`id`) == `div-inside-noscript` ){
          var obj_html = obj.html();  
          $(`#show`).html(obj_html);
        }        
      });
      //if you want remove noscript tag
      noscript_main.remove();      
 </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).