# jQuery:Extract text from noscript tag

Tags: jquery

I have this markup:

```
<div id="child1">
    <noscript>
        <h1>heading of Tab 1</h1>
    </noscript>
    <p>lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to extract information about the `h1` tag inside the `noscript` tag:

```
var noscript_tag = $(this).find('noscript');
var h1_tag = $(noscript_tag[0]).find('h1');
console.log($(h1_tag[0]));
```

But I'm getting following as output:

```
[]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to do anything with `noscript` from JavaScript? The purpose of `noscript` is to have a fallback if JS is disabled. I don't see how this is useful.

Comment: That's the whole purpose.Actually I'm developing a jquery plugin to add 'tabs' support.So when Javascript is disabled all the tabs will be displayed along with their headings in 'noscript' tags.But when Javascript is enabled,the plugin takes the headings from within the 'noscript' tag.

Comment: Then I don't see why you need a `noscript` tag at all... I mean, why put the markup in a `noscript` tag when you can just put it straight into `#child1` or whatever container you use use to identify your plugin. If JS is disabled then the contents won't change...

Comment: Hey,I used your way.It's working flawlessly.Thanks:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Contents of <noscript> with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620896/access-contents-of-noscript-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('noscript').text()
```

works in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Use the `noscript` inner text to create a DOM element (`h1` in this case) and grab the required text. Something like this:

```
$($("noscript").text()).filter("h1").text();​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<script>
function getVal() {
var nos = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript")[0]; 

var nosHtml = nos.textContent||nos.innerHTML; 

if ( nosHtml )
{
  var temp = document.createElement("h1");
  temp.innerHTML = nosHtml;

  document.body.appendChild(temp);
  var ex = document.getElementById("header");
  document.body.removeChild(temp);

  alert(ex.innerHTML);
}
}
</script>
<body onload="getVal();">
<div id="child1">
                <noscript>
                    <h1 id="header">heading of Tab 1</h1>
                </noscript>
                <p>lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="getVal();" value="Get" />
</body>
```